# How could I remove the superscript when I read excel using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

[the file is here](https://vpgcxpsypuuhqjhwgbselg.coursera-apps.org/notebooks/Energy%20Indicators.xls)I want to read an excel file using pandas. Some of the data have superscript in it. And when I use pd.read_excel() to read the file, the superscript numbers just appear. What should I do to remove the numbers?

For example, when the data is USA with superscript 13, the result I get from pandas is USA13. I just want to remove 13 from it and get USA instead.

Comment: Is it always the case the the non-superscript is letters and the superscript is numbers?

Comment: Sometimes they contain brackets, hyphens and spaces. They are all country or district names. But the superscripts are all numbers.

Comment: Could you provide an example that includes an exhaustive list of the cases you need to account for?

Comment: @NicholasZhaosi then you could probably do a regex sub of `'[0-9]'` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

Comment: I have just added the file link at the beginning..

Comment: It seems that I have got the answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
import string
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].apply(lambda x: x.strip(string.digits))
```

It seems that this works well with me.